# autofocus in html input tag only works once. Is there a way I can focus the input box automatically in another way?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm working on an in-browser editor that requires quick editing of single words. I'm trying to implement it by replacing specific words with input boxes containing those words and then allowing the user to edit that word on the spot.

Because I want the process to be quick, I want to make sure the input field is focused as soon as it is toggled, and my current solution is using the "autofocus" keyword in the input tag.

This works fine for the first edit after the page is loaded, but not for consequent ones.

### Demo video:

https://i.gyazo.com/0d1099b2f60b47ff504e3f5bab54fa8f.mp4

I've also tried implementing this using DOM manipulation, but for some reason, it isn't able to find the element with the tag, and I feel like it's because it's being dynamically generated.

### Relevant source code:

#### The HTML template

```
template: `
<div class="content" *ngFor="let sentence of sentences; let s_i = index;">
  <span class="content" *ngFor="let word of sentence; let i = index; trackBy:trackByFn">

    <span *ngIf="(currentIndex === i) && (currentSentence === s_i) && !(editing)"
          class="selectedWord"
          (click)="onClick(s_i, i)">{{word}} </span>
    <input *ngIf="(currentIndex === i) && (currentSentence === s_i) && (editing)"
          id="editingWord"
          (click)="onClick(s_i, i)"
          type="text"
          [(ngModel)]="sentences[s_i][i]"
          autofocus>
    <span *ngIf="(currentIndex !== i) || (currentSentence !== s_i)"
          (click)="onClick(s_i, i)">{{word}} </span>
  </span>
  <br>
</div>

<span class="content" *ngFor="let word of array; let i = index;"> 

</span>
`
```

#### My attempt using DOM manipulation to fix this

These methods are called when the edit key is pressed:

```
private editWord = function() {
  this.editing = true;
}

private focusWord = function() {
  console.log("Focusing word");
  var item = document.getElementsByClassName(".selectedWord");
  console.log(item);
  setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("#editingWord").focus(), 2000);
}
```

Additionally, is there a way to have all the characters highlighted when the input box is initially focused? This way the user can immediately start typing to replace the whole box.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.activeElement.blur()` before doing focus again.

Answer (score 0):

the more angular approach here is to use ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild('myInput', {static: false})
myInput;

private focusWord = function() {
    this.myInput.nativeElement.select(); // select focuses the input and selects text
}
```

this may present some timing issues using ngIf requiring timeouts and whatnot, so you could consider using a class instead to hide it:

```
<input [class.hidden]="(currentIndex === i) && (currentSentence === s_i) && (editing)"
      id="editingWord"
      (click)="onClick(s_i, i)"
      type="text"
      [(ngModel)]="sentences[s_i][i]">
```

with some css like `.hidden { display: none; }`

the most full featured / reusable solution would be to implement some kind of autoselect directive:

```
import { AfterContentInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[autoSelect]'
})
export class AutoSelectDirective implements AfterContentInit {

    public constructor(private el: ElementRef) { } // inject the element ref

    public ngAfterContentInit() { // run at the latest hook
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.el.nativeElement.select(); // run select after a timeout
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

you'd declare / import it as needed, and then usage is simple:

```
<input [class.hidden]="(currentIndex === i) && (currentSentence === s_i) && (editing)"
      id="editingWord"
      (click)="onClick(s_i, i)"
      type="text"
      [(ngModel)]="sentences[s_i][i]"
      autoSelect>
```